# Change Terminator profile from command line

Tags: bash, ubuntu-14.04, terminator

I have a Terminator profile (i.e. different bkgd colors, etc) that I use for production related scripts/consoles, but have to change the profile manually. Is there a way to change the profile at a bash level from within an open terminal window when launching production related scripts?

e.g

```
set_production_profile
heroku run rails console -a myprodapp
set_default_profile
```

Comment: Bash has no knowledge of your terminal emulator.

Comment: This question may be better suited for http://askubuntu.com/